# Set with small white, yellow, and purple boat and lime swimmer fins?

Tags: set-identification, friends

I have a part built boat, but need help in identifying the set so we can complete the build.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of [41000-1: Water Scooter Fun](https://brickset.com/sets/41000-1/Water-Scooter-Fun)

[image]